# Add a different ID to each li element by jQuery

Tags: jquery, html-lists

I'm new here and I'd like to ask a question about jQuery.

I have the unordered list like:

```
<ul id="pages">
    <li class="something"><a href="#"></a></li>
    <li class="something"><a href="#"></a></li>
    <li class="something"><a href="#"></a></li>
</ul>
```

And I'd like to add a different ID to every li displayed in this `<ul>` (eg. `<li class="something" id="li1">...`). Is there a way how to achieve this via jQuery?

Thanks a lot, Jakub

Answer (score 16, accepted):

As of jQuery 1.4, you can do this:

```
$('#pages li').attr('id', function(i) {
   return 'page'+(i+1);
});
```

In earlier versions, you'd need to write:

```
$('#pages li').each(function(i) {
    $(this).attr('id', 'page'+(i+1));
});
```

... which works in 1.4 as well. It's a matter of preference, I guess.

Comment: Wow, thanks a lot for fast reply! Works like a charm, both versions.

Thanks, Jakub