# How to get a different ID to each li element by JavaScript or jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have the unordered list like:
     
    
    Engineer 1
    Engineer 5
    Engineer 11

And I'd like to add a different ID to every li displayed in this . Is there a way how to achieve this via jQuery or Java Script?

`<li>` tags are getting dynamically.Some times it getting 3 or 10 or more tags.

Comment: Can you add the javascript that adds the `<li>` dynamically? The dynamic adding will need to be taken into account.

Comment: You can find a generic-code answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8714090/queryselector-wildcard-element-match/10824813#10824813
No jQuery necessary.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Use [**`jQueryElem.attr( attributeName, function )`**](http://api.jquery.com/attr/#attr-attributeName-function) when setting multiple `attributes` or using values returned by a `function`.

```js
$('#data li').attr('id', function() {
  return 'id_' + $(this).index();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="data">
  <li class="modal-ui-starting"><span style="margin-left: 10px;color: white;" class="glyphicon glyphicon-check"><a style="font-family: Arial,Verdana,sans-serif;text-decoration:none;" onclick="something.jsp" href="#"><span style="color:green;">Engineer 1</span>
    </a>
    </span>
  </li>
  <li class="modal-ui-starting"><span style="margin-left: 10px;color: white;" class="glyphicon glyphicon-check"><a style="font-family: Arial,Verdana,sans-serif;text-decoration:none;" onclick="something.jsp" href="#"><span style="color:green;">Engineer 5</span>
    </a>
    </span>
  </li>
  <li class="modal-ui-starting"><span style="margin-left: 10px;color: white;" class="glyphicon glyphicon-check"><a style="font-family: Arial,Verdana,sans-serif;text-decoration:none;" onclick="something.jsp" href="#"><span style="color:green;">Engineer 11</span>
    </a>
    </span>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Nice - very elegant solution!

Comment: @Rayon i added my script code in your code please once check it after tell me where id addyour code in my code

Answer (score 2):

This can be done fairly easily with vanilla JS...

You could loop through each instance of the class `modal-ui-starting` and append a unique ID, by using a counter which increments each time and adds this to an id.

```js
var lis = document.getElementsByClassName("modal-ui-starting");
var idinc = 0;
for (var i = 0; i < lis.length; i++) {
  idinc++;
  lis[i].id = "lisItem" + idinc;
}
```

```html
<ul id="data">
  <li class="modal-ui-starting"><span style="margin-left: 10px;color: white;" class="glyphicon glyphicon-check"><a style="font-family: Arial,Verdana,sans-serif;text-decoration:none;" onclick="something.jsp" href="#"><span style="color:green;">Engineer 1</span></a></span></li>
  <li class="modal-ui-starting"><span style="margin-left: 10px;color: white;" class="glyphicon glyphicon-check"><a style="font-family: Arial,Verdana,sans-serif;text-decoration:none;" onclick="something.jsp" href="#"><span style="color:green;">Engineer 5</span></a></span></li>
  <li class="modal-ui-starting"><span style="margin-left: 10px;color: white;" class="glyphicon glyphicon-check"><a style="font-family: Arial,Verdana,sans-serif;text-decoration:none;" onclick="something.jsp" href="#"><span style="color:green;">Engineer 11</span></a></span></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use callback function of `.attr()` which has index and old value as argument :

```
$('#data li').attr("id",function(i,o){
  return "data_li_" + i.toString();
});
```

**Working Snippet:**

```js
$('#data li').attr("id",function(i,o){
  return "data_li_" + i.toString();
});
console.log($('#data li'));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="data">
<li class="modal-ui-starting"><span style="margin-left: 10px;color: white;" class="glyphicon glyphicon-check"><a style="font-family: Arial,Verdana,sans-serif;text-decoration:none;" onclick="something.jsp" href="#"><span style="color:green;">Engineer 1</span></a></span></li>
<li class="modal-ui-starting"><span style="margin-left: 10px;color: white;" class="glyphicon glyphicon-check"><a style="font-family: Arial,Verdana,sans-serif;text-decoration:none;" onclick="something.jsp" href="#"><span style="color:green;">Engineer 5</span></a></span></li>
<li class="modal-ui-starting"><span style="margin-left: 10px;color: white;" class="glyphicon glyphicon-check"><a style="font-family: Arial,Verdana,sans-serif;text-decoration:none;" onclick="something.jsp" href="#"><span style="color:green;">Engineer 11</span></a></span></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

This jquery script adds "data-li-itemNumber" id to every element in ul

```js
$("#data").find("li").each(function(index){
 $(this).attr("id","data-li-"+index);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="data">
<li class="modal-ui-starting"><span style="margin-left: 10px;color: white;" class="glyphicon glyphicon-check"><a style="font-family: Arial,Verdana,sans-serif;text-decoration:none;" onclick="something.jsp" href="#"><span style="color:green;">Engineer 1</span></a></span></li>
<li class="modal-ui-starting"><span style="margin-left: 10px;color: white;" class="glyphicon glyphicon-check"><a style="font-family: Arial,Verdana,sans-serif;text-decoration:none;" onclick="something.jsp" href="#"><span style="color:green;">Engineer 5</span></a></span></li>
<li class="modal-ui-starting"><span style="margin-left: 10px;color: white;" class="glyphicon glyphicon-check"><a style="font-family: Arial,Verdana,sans-serif;text-decoration:none;" onclick="something.jsp" href="#"><span style="color:green;">Engineer 11</span></a></span></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function()
{
  $('#data li').each(function( index ) {
    $(this).attr('id','diff_'+index);
  });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

> As of jQuery 1.4, you can do this:
>
> ```
> $('#pages li').attr('id', function(i) {
>    return 'page'+(i+1);
> });
> ```
>
> earlier versions, you'd need to write:
>
> ```
> $('#pages li').each(function(i) {
>     $(this).attr('id', 'page'+(i+1));
> });
> ```
>
> ... which works in 1.4 as well. It's a matter of preference, I guess.

**Taken from:** [Add a different ID to each li element by jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2847561/add-a-different-id-to-each-li-element-by-jquery)

Comment: My question is different just wait bro,how to identify who is shifted my question is duplicate?

Comment: I did not shift it to duplicate, I only saw this answer on another question.